# Why when using a break my program crash?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I added in the MainActivity a button click event:

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                        {

                            try
                            {
                                response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                                break;     

                            } catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                text.setText("Connection Failed");
                            }
                        }
                        if (response!=null)
                        {
                            String a = null;
                            try
                            {
                                a = new String(response,"UTF-8");
                                text.setText(a);
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

I wanted to create a break when it's entering the try block after doing the `response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);` in order to stop the for loop.

The problem is that after it's done the `response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);` when it's supposed to be doing the break, my program crashes.

On the android device I get the message:

> unfortunately myapp has stopped

And when I click ok on the message the program just closes.

I can't figure out why the break makes the program crash.

This is the Get method:

```
private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;

        String urlStr = urlIn;
        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf); 

            byte[] bufOut;



            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
            }

            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stack trace? And why do you need the break if there's nothing running after the line?

Comment: Use `logcat` to see the logs. And by the way: almost every `android` related question should contain logs from `logcat`. It's way easier to help if you show logs.

Comment: How can you copy something or find something in the logcat ? I tried many times it's all scrolling there non stop. I tried to type in the filter window for example: exception but it didn't show me the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the crash is most likely apparent from the stacktrace that you haven't shown us.

But the logic of that loop is pretty dubious ... to me.

- Without the `break`, the loop iterates over all of the IP addresses, and tries `Get` on each one.  At the end, `response` will be the last value returned by a `Get` call, which may or may not be `null`.
- With the `break`, the loop terminates after the first IP address for which `Get` doesn't throw an exception ... irrespective of what the `Get` call returns.  (That could be `null`.)

These could be the cause of your crash, but it could be something else.  Either way, the logic is suspicious.  (And calling a method `Get` is bad style!)

**UPDATE**

Given that the `Get` method catches exceptions and returns `null` on failure, the recommended structure for the code that calls it is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++) {
        response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
        if (response != null) {
            break;     
        }
    }
    if (response == null) {
        // notify connection failed
    } else {
        // process response
    }
```

There is not need for a "belt and braces" `try {...} catch` in the calling code ... if you have already dealt with the *expected* exceptions in `Get`.  And (IMO) you should (almost) never catch `Exception`, because that is liable to conceal bugs.

Comment: Maybe i wrote this code in a wrong way. The logic of what i wanted to do is to start looping over the ip addresses in the array then i use the Get to send a command to a web server on my pc. If i sent the command to the server and i got a return meaning response is not null in this case i know the web server is sitting on this ip address. Once i get in return a string from the server i want to stop the loop and thread and assign this ip address to a global string variable. But the idea is to find from array of ip addresses which one the web server is sitting on now.

Comment: For now i know on what ip address my web server is sitting i also know the port. So i added to the array another fake not working ip addresses and port just to check my program.  The working the correct ip address is the first one in the array. But again the logic is to send a command to the web server and if i get a return if response is not null then i know this is the correct ip.

Comment: This is what i have in the array : ipaddresses[0] = "http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=nothing";
        ipaddresses[1] = "http://10.0.0.5:8088/?cmd=nothing"; and i used a breakpoint and it does send the command and it does send back from the server a string when checking if response is not null. But when i'm using a break; since i found the correct ip so i dont need to keep the loop anymore it throw the exception.

Comment: And i also using the get in another place in my code and it does working fine without any exceptions. The exception haapen only when i use the break in the place. Why break ? If the command sent fine i know this is the ip addresses so stop the loop no need to continue. Maybe i need to put the break after i'm checking if response is not null ? To move the if response is not null into the loop and then if i get return from the server if it's not null then break ?

Comment: The `break` does not cause the exception.  It hard to say what does ... until you show us the exception stack-trace.